# How to set value after the page redirecting?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, redirection

My scenario is set Taxonomy value after the page redirected.

```
if(($weight === "Above 90") && ($height === 'Above 7.0"')) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = $base_path . '/example/other/redirect-1';
    $term = taxonomy_term_load('371');
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($term->description); die;
    print render($term->description);
 }
```

Here, Once the condition is satisfied, its redirecting to the (/example/other/redirect-1)page.  But, the Taxonomy value is not displaying in this page.

I am not sure, whether I am doing in a right way, or Please guide me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `term_id` along with the `$form_state['redirect']` 
like 
  `$form_state['redirect'] = $base_path . '/example/other/redirect-1/?tid='.$term_id;`
and 
get the `term_id` in `/example/other/redirect-1/` page 
 write something  like below

```
 $term_id = $_GET['tid'];
 $term = taxonomy_term_load($term_id);
 print render($term->description);
```

I am giving you an idea some modification may need on code. You need to check.

Comment: did you solved that  issue!

Comment: No, I have setted the term id along with url , then URL will be changed like '/example/other/redirect-1/371'. Its not getting redirected to the page. I tried, but still I couldn't solve it .

Comment: try to sent the term_id in query string.

Comment: Your url will not change. Updated my answer little bit you can check.

Comment: Okay . i will try